# Why Apple allows apps which force users to vote 5-stars?

Tags: ios, app-store

There are many application in app store that they force users to vote 5 stars to unlock the content. That's forbidden by Apple but they don't care about it. I have at least 4-5 competitors which build very poor app but have more than thousand forced reviews.

Suprising thing is that even people complain about they are being forced in their reviews, Apple is not doing anything about that and those apps are in top 10 in their categories for more than a year. That's dissapointing and not fair!

Should we wear the black hat and do similar tricks to compete?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about app design / Apple App Store review policies instead of directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't suggest you using the same bad practice than your competitors, obviously it cause you to be down the research when user look for your product. To avoid that kind of situation, Apple offer this  [website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204084)

I've never use it before so I can't tell how effective it is.

After some more research, this website seems to be what you are [looking for](https://reportaproblem.apple.com/)

It's an absolutely unfair competition you're facing but as long as user won't complain or report to Apple those kind of situation, they won't do anything I guess.

Or maybe now users are OK with this kind of situation so it would mean that the rating system of the AppStore might be re-think in a better way.

Anyway you have only few options in your situation but reporting those app.

Since I've never seen similar situation in an app, may I ask what kind of app it is ?